# Print-friendly or printer friendly?

Tags: word-choice, difference, terminology

Which one is correct? **Print-friendly** or **printer friendly**? Moreover, should we use a *dash* with the first version?

Context: A PDF format is a great way to print documents.

Comment: I'd say both are acceptable, but also that both should have a dash.  Normally "printer-friendly" would be used.  For me "print-friendly" suggests something being appropriate for sending off to a print company for bulk production, rather than something for printing on the desktop.

Also, and this is way off topic, PDF isn't a great way to print documents.  It's a great way to _distribute_ and _view_ documents, but PDFs are formatted to fit a certain paper size and orientation, e.g. A4 or letter, portrait or landscape, so they don't add any great value to the printing process.

Comment: This seems like a great answer, thanks @ColinM.

Answer (score 2):

'Print' means so many things. It can mean the *process* of printing. It can also mean any text on paper (eg "*read the small print*").  So '*print-friendly*' could mean many things. It could mean that something *looks good* when printed. It could mean it is *easy* to print.

'Printer friendly' seems more specific. It would suggest that the format works well with a home printer.

I'd be happy with either describing PDF files. They are all of the above. A quick Google suggests to me that 'printer friendly' is the more popular option. It likely appeals to the average, non-technical computer user because it is referring to their peripheral by the most common name. It also feels the most technically correct to me, as most document formats can be printed, but what makes PDFs so useful in this respect is that they are (usually) pre-formatted to paper sizes used in home printers so that they look on paper as they do on screen. They are no more printable than other formats, but 'friendly' to printers in that they are ready-made for them without additional formatting.